# Custom sort in multi-level python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a python **dictionary** data.I am using **Python 3**.The dictionary is like bellow:

```
dct = {
    "3LHet": {
        "g35": {
            "exon": [
                [
                    "197631",
                    "197742",
                    "-"
                ],
                [
                    "198407",
                    "198470",
                    "-"
                ]

            ],
            "gene": [
                [
                    "197631",
                    "207214",
                    "-"
                ]
            ],
            "CDS": [
                [
                    "197631",
                    "197742",
                    "-"
                ],
                [
                    "198407",
                    "198470",
                    "-"
                ]

            ]
        },
        "g17": {
            "exon": [
                [
                    "2010292",
                    "2011137",
                    "+"
                ]
            ],
            "gene": [
                [
                    "2010292",
                    "2011137",
                    "+"
                ]
            ],
            "CDS": [
                [
                    "2010292",
                    "2011137",
                    "+"
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am accessing the dictionary in the bellow code.

```
for scaffold, scaffold_dct in dct.items():
    for gene, gene_dct in scaffold_dct.items():
        print(gene)
        for feature, feature_dct in gene_dct.items():
            print("\t"+feature)
```

**output:**

```
g35
    exon
    gene
    CDS
g17
    exon
    gene
    CDS
```

But I need the output in bellow format. Can someone please help me to solve the problem.

**Expected output:**

```
g17 
    gene
    CDS
    exon
g35
   gene
   CDS
   exon
```

Comment: Sorry, do you mean before g17 and then g35 because 17 comes before?

Comment: @ChiaraL yes , I need the sorting in two part i.e. (g17, g35) instead of (g35, g17) [numerical order ] and in gene, CDS, exon part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reorder these items since they're dictionaries, but you *can* order them when printing:

```
lookup = {'exon' : 1, 'cds' : 2, 'gene' : 3, }
for key, item in sorted(dct["3LHet"].items()):
    print(key)
    for subkey, subitem in sorted(item.items(), key=lambda x: lookup.get(x[0].lower(), 0)):
        print('  ', subkey)
```

You'll need to keep a lookup dict, so that the inner keys are displayed in the order you want.

Output:

```
g17
   gene
   CDS
   exon
g35
   gene
   CDS
   exon
```

If you've more inner keys that need explicit ordering, then just add then to your lookup.

Comment: Is this **lookup** dict case sensitive?

Comment: @Arijit Indeed it is. Is that an issue?

Comment: @COLDSPEED It becomes a bit problematic for me. so can please help me sort this part.

Comment: @Arijit Fixed. Defined all keys in `lookup` as lowercase and then made a small change in the lambda.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I am getting an error when I have a **new data entry in the gene, cds exon part** of the dictionary. So is it possible to put those new entries at the tail?

Comment: I've edited the lambda function again a little more, so that the error is not thrown. But if you want to sort that value explicitly, you'll need to specify it in the dict. Yes, it can go in the tail.